# Is it okay for columns with the same name on different tables to have different data types?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design

I'm looking for some guidance. Looking through one of our databases we have columns which are all named the same, lets say `X`. Now column `X` appears in multiple tables within the same database. However, across 10 columns there's an almost even division of number / varchar data types.

I was wondering if this is O.K or I should try to raise something to have this changed? From what I can see the real world data is all numerical.

Any help in advance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on whether column `X` is the same business attribute on ten different tables, or different attributes with the same column name.

> I was wondering if this is O.K ...

If the columns represent different business attributes, it's nasty that they share the same name but there probably isn't enough damage done to justify renaming them. It depends on the real name (assuming it's not really `X`).

If each column represents the same business attribute then it is definitely not okay for them to have different datatypes. The best that can happen is you have inefficient joins because Oracle has to cast the character columns to number values. At worst you have opened the gateway to data corruption, and your columns which should only contain numeric values now contain non-numeric values, which cannot be converted and will cause queries to fail. The lessons of history are that such data corruption will happen eventually.

> … or  I should try to raise something to have this changed

In an ideal world you should change this. Of course, in an ideal world you wouldn't have to :-)

The practicalities are, having a consistent physical data model is always a good thing but you'll probably struggle to convince people of the value of doing this.

At the very least there's a lot of effort required, because you can't simply ALTER TABLE … MODIFY to change the datatype of a populated column. You need to add a new column, port the data across, drop the old column, rename the new column and re-apply any constraints, indexes, etc. Then there's the regression testing of the applications which use the tables in question.

That's the happy path: what happens if you discover that the data corruption has happened and you have non-numeric data in those columns? Now it gets really messy.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, `X` is OK, but I prefer naming them `X_THIS` and `X_THAT` because - although *best practices* say that you should always precede column name with table (alias), when your query looks like

```
select a.x, b.x, c.x
from emp a join dept b on a.deptno = b.deptno
join job c on c.job = a.job
```

it is difficult to see (at first sight) what's going on. But, if you have

```
select a.x_emp, b.x_dept, c.x_job
from emp a join dept b on a.deptno = b.deptno
join job c on c.job = a.job
```

then your life is somewhat easier as you don't have to create aliases for column names.

Comment: Hi guys - thanks for the responses, to better inform the business use the column to store the same data throughout, it's an account identifier, it's not the end of the world I guess because the data fits but going forward it'd be nice to enforce proper standards and practices. - Will definitely take into consideration your comments about aliasing @Littlefoot and I hope I've answered your question @ APC